# Path of the file stored in s3 does not match with provided - Using Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm building a service to upload images with laravel and stored in a aws s3 bucket, this is the function responsible for store image.

```
public function fromUrl(Request $request)
{
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'files'   => 'required|array|min:1',
    'files.*' => 'string',
  ]);

  if (!$validator->fails()) {
    $paths = [];
    foreach ($validator->validate()['files'] as $file) {
      $url = config('services.s3.host') . Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/public', file_get_contents($file), 'public');
      array_push($paths, $url);
    }
    return $paths;
  } else {
    throw new ValidateException([
      'message' => $validator->errors()->toArray(),
      'rules' => $validator->failed()
    ]);
  }
}
```

The request body looks like this.

```
{
  "files": [
    "https://image-url-1",
    "https://image-url-2"
  ]
}
```

I expect that the path returned when saving the image is something like this.

```
[
  "https://my-bucket-url/images/public/random-name-for-image1",
  "https://my-bucket-url/images/public/random-name-for-image2"
]
```

but instead I'm getting the following.

```
[
  "https://my-bucket-url/1",
  "https://my-bucket-url/1"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing put in your example.

Firstly the first parameter is the path plus filename and you have no filename random logic. The third parameter is options array.

```
$randomFileName = uniqid(rand(), true);

$path = 'images/public/' . $randomFileName;

Storage::disk('s3')->put($path, file_get_contents($file));
```

This code will save an element at `images/public/$randomFileName`. To return the proper path you can use the `url()` method.

```
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);

 array_push($paths, $url);
```

Comment: you're right. There was no filename random logic because the laravel documentation says that the put() method automatically generates a name, but it doesn't apply for this case.

Comment: Only on putFile which has some other quirks. Put is the safe bet imo :)